# Swing GUI generator for XML

Tags: java, xml, swing, schema, dtd

My application has an XML configuration file which users now edit in a text editor. I want to provide a (Swing) form for editing this configuration. I have a DTD for the XML, but the application does not accept all XML documents validated by the DTD i.e. the application imposes more restrictions than those in the DTD.

I was about to start hacking to see how to go about doing this, but I thought I'd ask around for approaches others have used. Are there libraries out there which generates an editor, given a DTD? Any tips, ideas etc?

**PS:** My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983399/create-a-gui-from-a-xml-schema-automatically) except that I need a Swing GUI.

Comment: Do you mean something like http://www.felixgolubov.com/XMLEditor/ ? A swing component that is able to edit XML documents?

Comment: I don't know if I understand well, but try read about JAXB, maybe its useful.

Comment: any luck on finding such tool. If so can you please post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Other than your basic SAX or DOM type libraries, I don't think there is such a solution. It'll probably be a bit difficult to have a one size fits all solution based off of a DTD because the organization of data in XML doesn't necessarily correspond directly with the use or implementation of that data.